# bxSlider sticks on last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I'm stuck here. I'm using bxSlider to display advertisers at the top of this page http://shorthorn.org. The slides pause for 8 seconds before rotating but for some reason when it gets to the last slide it seems to stick for 60+ seconds before finally rotating over to the first slide. I don't see any javascript errors or anything. Code is below.

```
<div class="header-advertising">
            <?php
            adsanity_show_ad_group(
                array(
                    'group_ids' => array(6), // an array of valid group ids (you can get these from the main list of ad groups
                    'num_ads'   => -1, // number of ads to show total
                    'num_columns'   => 1, // number of ads to show per row
                )
            );
            ?>
        </div>


 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.header-advertising').bxSlider({
          auto: true,
          controls: false,
          pager: false,
          speed: 1000,
          pause: 8000,
          randomStart: true
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Remove the `randomStart` property.

Comment: Yeah that's when this started. They want the sponsors to be randomized to make it fair to all of them. Is there an alternative to randomizing it if I remove that?